# Accesing WordPress API within my PHP app

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm accessing the WordPress API from within my PHP code just including the wp-blog-header.php and using get_posts().

This is working ok when my PHP code is at the same level than the WP directory. For example:

```
/blog/[..wp files..]
/index.php
```

At index.php, I have:

```
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
$post = get_posts(...);
```

and is working pretty well.

BUT, when I try to do the same with the code inside a directory, for example:

```
/blog/[..wp files..]
/folder/index.php
```

and at folder/index.php I have:

```
require('../blog/wp-blog-header.php');
$post = get_posts(...);
```

this always makes my app to redirect to the WP installation (wp-admin/install.php) and doesn't work.

Any idea ? Can the API be used from within a directory ?

The blog is configured correctly and is working ok by itself.

---

Edit: Stack trace showing when the app redirects to wp_not_installed() when used inside a folder

```
6   0.4052  3402748 require_once( '/usr/www/juanjo/NuevaWebJuanjo/blog/wp-load.php' )   ../class_wordpress.php:11
7   0.4054  3408296 require_once( '/usr/www/juanjo/NuevaWebJuanjo/blog/wp-config.php' ) ../wp-load.php:30
8   0.4063  3487064 require_once( '/usr/www/juanjo/NuevaWebJuanjo/blog/wp-settings.php' )   ../wp-config.php:19
9   1.3650  6103276 wp_not_installed( ) ../wp-settings.php:100
10  1.6258  7676148 wp_redirect( )  ../load.php:408
11  1.6261  7684480 header ( )  ../pluggable.php:890
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edited the question to add a stack trace when the require() fail and redirect to wp_not_installed();

Comment: @ Juanjico - did you get anywhere with this issue, I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For everything wordpress that is accessed outside wordpress system, you HAVE to include `wp-load.php`

```
include("/absolute/path/to/wp-load.php");
//do whatever you want
```

Comment: This is even worse. If I replace require('blog/wp-blog-header.php'); by require('blog/wp-load.php'); it always call wp_not_installed() not matter if my app is in the root or inside a folder. Thanks anyway.

Comment: please, can you just try in any of your projects to include WP from within a folder? Just create a folder, put an index.php with the include() and see if you got redirected to the install ? I don't know if the problem is the WP itself (bad configuration) or what. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think @silent means that you need to have both included for it to work. I however need both when I'm running WordPress.

Comment: If I just do require('blog/wp-blog-header.php'); redirects to wp_not_installed() (when used inside a folder, not in root). If I just do require('blog/wp-load.php'); redirect to wp_not_installed() to (inside a folder or in root). So, it's impossible to include both, because the first redirects to wp_not_installed() and never execute the second require().

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://www.webopius.com/content/139/using-the-wordpress-api-from-pages-outside-of-wordpress

Apparently adding:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
```

right before:

```
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

does the trick.